# Getting size of query results

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I'm in the process of deleting certain data from various tables, before I delete them I need to spool the applicable data to a file.

I need to be able to know the size of the data I will spool beforehand.

For example; I will be using something like the query below to spool the data and using the same conditions delete applicable data:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE sold_date IS NOT NULL AND restock_prod = 1
```

Using these conditions is there a way I can find out beforehand size of the query results?

Am using SQLPlus and just want to query and have it return the size of results.

Comment: You can use **count** functions to get the size of query result.

Comment: @NisheshPratap doesn't **count** only return the number of rows? Not the size in bytes.

Comment: The answer to your question would be table-dependent, and I think you might only be able to know if executing the actual query.  Please show us the definition for your table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The data I'm extracting to file then deleting from the table is all NUMBER(38), I just need some kind of size reference for when the actual extraction takes place so I can compare the size of the file the data was extracted to; to the size I previously got.

Comment: @Genos, I am not familiar with sqlplus, but I did a quick google search for "sqlplus query statistics", which took me to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96533/autotrac.htm - maybe you could use one of the statistics? There are a few there for byte size. (Not sure how to actually get the statistics out as part of the call either, but it's a start!)

Comment: @AndrewP **autotrace** was my first thought, the problem is you can't isolate only the query results size. It includes all communication packet sizes too.

Comment: Can you pull the entire resultset down and check it's size in memory? Size in SQL probably doesn't equate to size on disc, depending on how you choose to serialize it. Could you do the serialization server-side and get the length? e.g. in mssql, you could do `FOR XML ()`, and then get the len() of that. If one was to write the xml to disc, it'd be a great match. If I wanted serialize the data as JSON, the SQL server would have no idea how big it would be. Another option would be to inspect the schema for the table, get size of each column * record count (at least, as a max size)

Comment: @AndrewP found something along those lines, it seems you can output to isolate results from different actions and show only the output of the **SELECT** statement. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_eight.htm (and of course using **SET AUTOTRACE TRACEONLY**)

Comment: With SQL\*Plus the file size may depend largely on the settings used.  For example, with a large `set linesize` and no `trimspool` the size of the file may be huge for even the smallest amount of data.  Are you sure you want to use SQL\*Plus for this task?  It would suck to lose data because of a client formatting issue.  Export datapump would be a much more reliable way to save data.

Comment: @JonHeller I 100% agree with you and if I had any say in the matter I would absolutely not be exporting in this way. Unfortunately I don't have a say in the matter and just have to find the best way to proceed. That is also one of the reasons I want to have be able to confirm that the size of the query results matches the size of the export file to see if I'm losing any data.

Comment: The value of `bytes sent via SQL*Net to client` from the output of `set autotrace traceonly STATISTICS` is a a pretty good estimation of the total size of the result. However, the size of a text file storing that data would be bigger though. e.g. the number `123456` only needs 4 bytes to be stored (and sent) but would require 6 bytes in a text file. You also have the overhead of the column delimiter and line endings.